# Error processing response stream. The XML element contains mixed content

Tags: asp.net, wcf, asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4, wcf-data-services

I'm calling a stored procedure via WCf-DataService and EF4. Other method works fine but one which return List failed with the exception **Error processing response stream. The XML element contains mixed content.**

Here is the XML return by the method (call in http)

```
<GetShowName>
    <element>MONT</element>
    <element>INTERPEECH 08/2011</element>
    <element>POI MOBILIER 09/2011</element>
    <element>ASSEMBLE GALE CLUB 41 06/2011</element>
    <element>AFTES 10/2011</element>
    <element>DIVERS DEVIS 12/2011</element>
    <element>DIVERS DEVIS 12/2011</element>
    <element>SFTS 2011</element>
    <element>COUPE DU MONDE BIATHLON 12/11</element>
    <element>CADRE NOIR GENEVE 04/2011</element>
</GetShowName>
```

And the code is:

```
private List<T> ListWithFilter<T>(string methodName, string methodParameters)
{
    StringBuilder methodParams = new StringBuilder("/" + methodName + "?");
    methodParams.Append(methodParameters);

    Uri methodUri = new Uri(entities.BaseUri + methodParams.ToString());
    List<T> result = entities.Execute<T>(methodUri).ToList(); //Exception here

    return result;
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

According to this post the client does not support primitive type materialization as of .NET 4.0.  May need to parse the result manually:

[Invoking a WebGet throws an exception](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetdataservices/thread/7c71eff7-4951-480f-bbc1-b00046ee788b)

Comment: This is because WCF Data Services is a neglected and half-hearted library full of bugs and short-comings.